# Ajax calling MVC action method - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm making the following AJAX call to an action method in an ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: appControllerUrl + "/SaveAppDetails",
        data: {appDetails: JSON.stringify(appDetailsView.model)},
        processData: true,
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

However I get an HTTP 500 error stating 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object'. Here is my controller:

```
public class AppDetailsController
{
    // GET: AppDetails
    AppDetailsController() { }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAppDetails(string appDetails)
    {
       ...
    }
```

The 'data' that the Ajax call passes to the controller looks this this:

```
appDetails= {"id":{"type":"string"},"appName":{"type":"string"},"guid":21}
```

... so it looks like the actual data I need isn't being passed, however the data string itself seems to be well formed. What's causing the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that MVC is trying to instantiate a controller but cannot do so. In C#, if you declare a constructor and don't specify an accessibility modifier, it will be `private`. You should add the `public` modifier to the constructor of `AppDetailsController`.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript Example**

```
appDetailsView.model = {
         Id: $.trim(idExample),
         AppName: $.trim(appNameExample),
         Guid: 21
      };
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: appControllerUrl + "/SaveAppDetails",
        data: JSON.stringify(appDetailsView.model),
        processData: true,
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

**Action**

```
public class AppDetailsController
{
    // GET: AppDetails
    public AppDetailsController() { }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAppDetails(AppDetailsView appDetails)
    {
       ...
    }
```

**Class View Model**

```
public class AppDetailsView{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string AppName { get; set; }
     public int Guid { get; set; }
}
```